# react-naitve Component 'RNCamera' re-registered bubbling event 'topPictureTaken' as a direct event moduleConstantsForComponent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

[image: react-native RNCamera issue]

#### Does anyone have any idea about this issue?

I am using 
     
    `"react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-native": "^0.61.5",
    "react-native-camera": "^3.13.1",`

#### Mac-os - vesions 10.15.1

#### Nodejs - version v10.16.0

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I will leave the answer so it helps anyone in the future with the same issue.

This problem happens when use the react-native-camera library with the react-native-document-scanner library as both have an event with the same name called **onPictureTake** which is causing this problem.

The solution would be to manually rename the name of this event by searching for 'onPictureTake' and replacing all it occurrences inside the .h and .m files for one library. Unfortunately, you will need to do this change every time you update the pods.